# How to insert a half line space (preferably adjustable) in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long article and from place to palce the chunks of text have to be separated by empty rows like in the example:

Example:

Text 1

Text 2

Text 3

I need the spaces to be half the size of the text characters. For example, if the letters above the space are size 12, the space should be size 6 (preferably a dimension that I can adjust not necessary exactly 6).

When I rezise the text, this is quite important, the size of the white lines has to modify accordingly automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: best way to use styles and set paragraph settings: "space after" to the desired value. When change font size you need to update "space after" too. If you really want to make it automatic, then you need to use macro. (There are several great tutorial on the internet).

Comment: Not all the paragraphs are separated by white rows. Some of them just start with a TAB. In my case those spaces are completely random, they appear even in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: Could you please paste a screenshot to see how random the situation is with you?